# Catalina import iTunes Library.xml from Music app

Tags: itunes, music, beta, catalina

I formatted my Mac Catalina beta, because I expected the redesigned Music app to successfully import iTunes Library.itl file from Time Machine Backup.

However, when I import > select the file, nothing happens and even if I manually add ~/Library/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music file into Music app, some of the music files are missing.

Is there any way to completely reset Music app's preferences, thereby re-initiating iTunes Library import sequence from OS update? Or, is there a way to properly import previous iTunes Library from Music app?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `~/Music/Previous iTunes Libraries/`. There are old copies of your .itl file stored there.

See: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT203225